# Is there a way to choose where to save a file (via a pop-up window) in python?

Tags: python, download

I want a user to be able to choose where to save a file through one of [these windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpLGh.jpg), but I don't know how.

So far all I have for downloading is

```py
dst_folder = input("Enter in the folder you want to download this file to: ")
stream.download(dst_folder)
```

This works, but you can type in literally anything for the input.

Comment: What window/GUI framework are you using?

Comment: "This works, but you can type in literally anything for the input." You realistically will still have to validate the name that you get back. Or more realistically, live with the fact that saving a file can fail for other reasons besides an "invalid" name/path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this method

```
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.withdraw()

# Ask the user to select a folder
folder_selected = filedialog.askdirectory()

# Use the selected folder to download the file
stream.download(folder_selected)
```